# How to add records to MS Access via Java

Tags: java, database

Im trying to add a row of records to my already existing MS database.
Basically these records are to be entered into a GUI and then added to the database when the user clicks submit.

I've created the GUI, using 3 JLabel's, 3 JTextfield's and 1 JButton.
The user needs to enter a name, quantity and price and click the submit button.

```
JLabel newproductname = new JLabel("Enter Product Name");
JTextField npn = new JTextField(7);
JLabel newproductprice = new JLabel("Enter Product Price");
JTextField npp = new JTextField(7);
JLabel newproductstock = new JLabel("Enter Product Stock");
JTextField nps = new JTextField(7);
JButton addnewitem = new JButton("Add New Item");
```

This is what i have used to create the GUI, obviously i have added all of this to a panel below

I'm new to Java so i'd appreciate terminology in something anyone can understand, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionListioner event for that. when you will click on button, an event will fired,that event will be handled through ActionListioner interface([event handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) ), its has one method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) you need to give implementation of this method to handle you event. i-e

```
class GUI implements ActionListener{
   JLabel newproductname = new JLabel("Enter Product Name");
JTextField npn = new JTextField(7);
JLabel newproductprice = new JLabel("Enter Product Price");
JTextField npp = new JTextField(7);
JLabel newproductstock = new JLabel("Enter Product Stock");
JTextField nps = new JTextField(7);
JButton addnewitem = new JButton("Add New Item");

void storeMethod(String npn, string npp, string nps){
   // some implementation 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    storeMethod(npn.getText(), npp.getText(), nps.getText());
}

void drawForm(){
 // some implementation
addnewitem.addActionListener(this);
}

main(){
new GUI().drawForm();
}
```

}

here is a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35018/Access-MS-Access-Databases-from-Java) which will help you in connectivity with MS-Assess. 
from here you will find source code [link2](http://www.sourcecodester.com/java/jdbc-odbc-connectivity-java-with-access.html)

Comment: Please do, i know of how to edit records, for example changing the name of an item. But i need to know how to enter items to a new row

Comment: The rows of data that are already in the database i put in when i created the database. My Java program can pull this data from the database and display it in a textfield on the Java GUI. I can change some of the values within the database using Java as well, for example, the amount of stock can be updated via Java and it changes the stock amount in the database. Im after a way to add a name, price and stock amount into a new row within the database using the Java GUI. I looked at the links that i was sent, unfortunately, most of the content was way to advanced for me

Answer (score 0):

To add your record in MS Access using Java you need to use JDBC to insert records.
[Refer Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujJ4H9RpC7c)